# set material design tab transitions (web)

Tags: web, material-design

I have been working with material design and tried all options as instructed at [https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.components.tabs/directive/mdTab][1]

I have no clue as to how to change the slide transitions to fade or anything else. Please help

```
<md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex">
 <img ng-src="img/angular.png" class="centered">
 <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs | orderBy:predicate:reversed" md-on-select="onTabSelected(tab)" md-on-deselect="announceDeselected(tab)" ng-disabled="tab.disabled">
   <md-tab-label>
  {{tab.title}}
    <img src="img/removeTab.png" ng-click="removeTab(tab)" class="delete">
  </md-tab-label>
    <md-tab-body>
  {{tab.content}}
    </md-tab-body>
   </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the animation with css using these classes:

```
[role="tabpanel"],
md-tabs {
  transition: none; /* or whatever transition you want
}
```